# Prove |Re z| less than or equal to |z| and |Im z| less than or |z|

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

$|Re (z)|\le|z|\qquad$ $(z := x + yi)$

$|Re (z)|= |x|=\sqrt{x^2}\qquad
 |z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$

$\sqrt{x^2}\le \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ (therefore $y^2 \ge 0$)

then the answer is $\sqrt{x²}\le \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ is this correct?

and do the same thing for $Im(z)$?

is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $Re(z)$ and $Im(z)$ are real, so their squares are non-negative, so $Re(z)^2,Im(z)^2\le Re(z)^2+Im(z)^2$

Comment: Here's the [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) tutorial for typesetting mathematical terms.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand what the line "|Re z|= |x| --> sqrt(x^2) |z| = sqrt(x^2 + y^2) " was supposed to mean.  Or what you meant when you referred to "the answer" or why the "therefore" follows".  But after reading a third time I *think* you mean:  $|Re(z)|=|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ and $|z|=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $\sqrt{x^2}\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$  BECAUSE $y^2 \ge 0$ ("therefore" means $y^2\ge 0$ because $\sqrt{x^2}\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and not the other way around). But, yes  That is correct.

Comment: Note for real numbers: $\sqrt{A} \le \sqrt{B}\iff 0\le A \le B$ And so $\sqrt{x^2}\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\iff x^2\le x^2 + y^2\iff 0\le y^2$ which is always true for real numbers.  ... Also note as $x,y$ are real numbers they are form two legs of a right triangle with hypotenuse of $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.  Each leg must be *shorter* than the hypotenuse.  Also note $|x| + |y| \ge \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \ge |x^2|$ or $|y^2|$ and those are *equal* if and only if one of $x$ or $y$ is zero

Comment: @fleablood, why not the other way around?

Comment: What do you mean why not the other way around?  $y^2 \ge 0$ is the reason why $\sqrt{x^2}\le \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.   But $\sqrt{x^2} \le \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ is *not* the reason why $y^2 > 0$.  Also, up till that point we have utterly no reason to believe $\sqrt{x^2}\le \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.  The *reason* $\sqrt{x^2}\le \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ is *BECAUSE* $y^2\ge 0$.  Not the other way.  You can *NEVER* say RESULT therefore REASON.  Or  because of the RESULT we have the REASON.  We can *ONLY* do it the other way around:  REASON therefore RESULT, or because of the REASON we have the RESULT.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is pretty much correct. Just to give a bit more intuition for what's going on, consider the diagram below, showing a complex number on the Argand diagram.

We see that $x=\text{Re }z, y = \text{Im }z$ are the two shorter sides of a right-angled triangle, and its hypothenuse is $\lvert z\rvert$. It is visually very clear that $\lvert z\rvert \geq \lvert x\rvert, \lvert y\rvert$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is almost correct. You should have added that, when you write $z$ as $x+yi$, your numbers $x$ and and $y$ are real (although, yes, this is usually implicit). And you also should have added that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=|\operatorname{Re}z|$.

Comment: so I had to simplify it. I was wondering like I had to prove it. haha.

Comment: Are you talking about the equality $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$?